# Audio delay (several minutes) solution

Tags: delay, streaming

Trying to find a solution for an audio delay/buffer device (in the order of 10-15 minutes or so).

I have an analog audio source providing line level audio which I want to delay by a fixed amount (we'll say 10 minutes), then pass it along to an IP converter - like an instreamer. This would be running unattended 24/7

Obviously there is five figure broadcast equipment, but hoping something a little more down and dirty. Not sure if there is a software-based solution out there.

Comment: Maybe with the audio delay options in OBS https://obsproject.com/ but i'm not sure it will go to 10 or 15 minutes.

Comment: Thinking outside the box a bit - if you record to file in one structure, then play it back from another, you could offset the times by as long as you like. At least then you wouldn't have to be holding 15 mins in RAM. Something like [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) might be able to do something like this, though I've never tried. It can record to file, it can be timed, it can stream to shoutcast etc. I think there's a free demo.

Comment: You can also do this with some simple coding in Python or C# too - write the audio stream to a temp file, and broadcast it whenever you want. I'm not 100% on the broadcasting bit, but definitely another dirty approach to consider. You could use an RPi or Arduino board to do it in-line.